# scp attempt in a bash script triggered by cron fails; works when run script manually

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, scp

Trying to scp a file in a bash script that's scheduled by cron. 
When cron triggers it, the scp fails with a permission denied error message.  When I run the script manually using a command like:

```
/etc/scripts>  bash script3
```

the scp command works just fine.

From a previous question about how to troubleshoot cron jobs in general, I learned that the environment variables might be different between when i'm running via command line manually and when cron runs.  So in following one of the suggested troubleshooting tip, I scheduled the following job via cron:

```
lab-1:/etc/scripts# cat cronenvtest         
OFILE=/tmp/crons.environment                                      
(/usr/bin/whoami                                                  
/usr/bin/env ) > $OFILE 2>&1
```

The output looks like this:

```
lab-1:/var/www/# tail -f /tmp/crons.environment
HOME=/root
RC_SVCNAME=crond
LOGNAME=root
RC_SERVICE=/etc/init.d/crond
TERM=screen
SVCNAME=crond
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
LANG=en.utf8
SHELL=/bin/sh
PWD=/root
```

When I run "env" on the command line, it looks like this:

```
lab-1:/tmp# env                                            
SSH_CLIENT=10.1.1.1 57728 22                                                
USER=root                                                                        
MAIL=/var/mail/root                                                              
SHLVL=1                                                                          
OLDPWD=/etc/scripts                                                              
HOME=/root                                                                       
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/4                                                               
PAGER=less                                                                       
PS1=\h:\w\$                                                                      
LOGNAME=root                                                                     
TERM=screen                                                                      
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin                
LANG=en.utf8                                                                     
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-eGvX0isT3V/agent.22951                                    
SHELL=/bin/ash                                                                   
PWD=/tmp                                                                         
CHARSET=UTF-8                                                                    
SSH_CONNECTION=10.1.1.1 57728 10.2.2.2 22
```

Here's the line in the script that tries to do the scp:

```
 scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null @$server:/tmp/"$server.db" "$dir/"
```

**What I've tried so far**

I tried to change the scp command to include the root user, like so:

```
scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null root@$server:/tmp/$"server.db" "$dir/"
```

Tried to change the destination from $dir variable to a hardcoded path like "/tmp"

Tried to add the following line to the bash script, right before the scp:

```
PWD=/etc/scripts
```

So far, none of this has worked. 
Any tips?

Comment: You have an active SSH authentication agent, which is something the cron script won't have. So run `unset SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and then try the scp command again. If it starts failing, it's because your SSH agent is supplying the key for the authentication. Without the agent, the `scp` command may need to prompt for a passphrase, or the private key might not be in place.

Comment: I think that's what the problem is.  Thanks